# How can I mark changing elements in the bubble sort algorithm by *

Tags: c

```
//bubble sort algorithm 

#include<stdio.h>

#include<conio.h>

#include<stddef.h>

#define SIZE 10

//function main begins program execution 

int main( void )
{
    
    //initialize a 
    int a[ SIZE ] = { 2, 6, 4, 8, 10, 12, 89, 68, 45, 37 };

    int pass;// pass counter 
    size_t i;// comparisons counter 
    int hold;// temporary location used to swap array elements 
    
    
    puts("Data items in original order: ");
    
    //output original array

    for( i = 0;i < SIZE;++i )
    {
        printf("%4d",a[ i ] );

    }//end for 
    
    //bubble sort 
    //loop to control number of passes 

    for( pass = 1;pass < SIZE;++pass )
    {
        int flag = 0;

        //loop to control number of passes 

        for( i = 0;i < SIZE - pass; ++i )
        {
            //compare adjactent elements and swap them if first 
            //element is greater than second element 

            if( a[ i ] > a[ i + 1 ] )
            {
                hold = a[ i ];

                a[ i ] = a[ i + 1 ];

                a[ i + 1 ] = hold;

                flag = 1;

            }//end if 

        }//end inner for

        if(flag == 1)
        {
            printf("*");

         } 
    }//end outer for 
    
    puts("\nData items in ascending order: ");
    
    //output sorted array

    for( i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i )
    {
        printf("%4d",a[ i ] );
        
    }//end for 
    
    puts("");
    
        getch();

             return 0;

}//end main
```

What is the reason why * is incorrect in the picture below

> deitel how to program  problem 6.11b ) the data in the array may already be in the
> proper or near-proper order,so why make nine passes if fewer will suffice?Modify the sort to check at the end of each pass whether any swaps have been made.If none has been made, then the data must already be in the proper order,so the program should terminate.If swaps have been made,then at least one more pass is needed.

How can I mark * under displacements

[image]

Comment: you have to keep an array of changes, and print that array after the data line is printed.

Comment: Are you asking how to print the asterisks so each is under the element it swaps (the first or the second or near the middle?)? If so, print a newline character after printing the elements and then, when you are about to print an asterisk, print enough spaces to put it in the desired place. You will have to keep a count of how many characters have been printed on the line so far. E.g., if the first asterisk marked element 3 swapping with element 4, and the next asterisk will mark element 8 swapping with element 9, you need to print enough spaces for 5 elements. After each pass, print a newline.

Comment: When you swap, [print the marks](https://ideone.com/zjvE0b) in the approriate postions for `i`and `i + 1`. If you choose the same width for each array element, you can calculate the position easily. A varable field width in `printf`, eg printf(`"%*s", pos, "*")` comes in handy, but you can also print spaces in a loop.